# Getting zsh: command not found in mac terminal for each and every command

Tags: android, macos, installation, appium, zshrc

I am working on installation of appium in macbook(MacOS Catalina)

**Issue:**

following right steps of installation, but my terminal is acting weird now.
It is displaying **zsh: command not found:** for every command I am hitting.

even though I am having that particular software configured in my machine.
i.e
while I am hitting

- npm install -g authorize-ios
- nano ~/.zsh_profile
- sudo nano ~/.zshrc
- touch .zshrc
- clear

I am getting below errors

1. zsh: command not found: npm zsh:
2. command not found: sudo
3. zsh: command not found: touch

4.command not found: clear

5.[getting this error while installing anything through terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdw8E.jpg)

My terminal is showing this by default while I open [Terminal is showing this by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p2dO.png)

I am doubting I have been messed up with $PATH variable
I am getting below result while performing
echo $PATH

> /Users/hemanshimaheta/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:/Users/hemanshimaheta/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/hemanshimaheta/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:$

**Solution I have tried:**

I have tried below command

> export
> PATH=":/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/hemanshimaheta/opt/bin/$PATH"

after hitting above one, few commands started working(however installation command still giving error like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvyoI.jpg)) but once I am closing terminal and opening it,same issue occurring again. It is not looking fixed permanently.

I really need appium to get installed in my machine but due to this I am not able to move further.
Please someone help me with this.

Comment: I believe your `PATH` variable ends with an extraneous $. And the new assignment you attempted needs a colon before `$PATH`.

Comment: @Howlium Thanks for considering my query.
I have tried adding colon but still I am getting same error

Comment: you need try exit() command once complete it you can access other command I had same issue before.